# Method not recognized even though it is from the same class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Recently, I've come across this problem where I had two methods in a class. One was referring to another but the other wasn't being recognized even though I could execute them individually.

```
class ButtonProcessor {
    buttonClick() {
        this.otherMethod();
    }

    otherMethod() {
        console.log("This does not work!");
    }
}

var buttonProcessor = ButtonProcessor;

document.getElementById("button").onclick = buttonProcessor.buttonClick;
```

The first method was called from a button click which was associated with a callback to that method.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I found for this is to make the method that is called by the button a seperate function from the class and make it reference a class object that was already being used else-where. This is because apparently, when a method is referenced in a callback, using this to refer to another method doesn't work, because the callback only considers that one method.

```
class ButtonProcessor {

    otherMethod() {
        console.log("This does work!");
    }
}

var buttonProcessor = ButtonProcessor;

function buttonClick() {
    buttonProcessor.otherMethod();
}

document.getElementById("button").onclick = buttonProcessor.buttonClick;
```

Could there be another way to fix this?

Comment: This is one of the most often-duplicated questions on the site. It doesn't need to be answered, it's already thoroughly answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder one thing though, is that these other questions are hard to find.

Comment: All due respect, this one isn't.

Comment: I mean, not everyone knows that the problem is the "this" in the callback, so they probably won't search for that and won't find that question and that answer.

Comment: Well to a lot of people it is baffling why one function in a javascript class cannot see another function in the same class.